# Find value of $m$ such that $y =mx$ and $y=\frac x{x^2+1}$ enclose a region

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

For what values of $m$ do the line
$$y =mx$$ and the curve
$$y=\frac x{1+x^2}$$
enclose a region? Find the
area of the region.

I did the integration but I was unable to solve this question. Please help me in this question ?

Comment: Can you draw a picture? Did you try to graph that function?

Comment: Doing the integration presumably means you found an indefinite integral of *some* function, but in order to do the correct integration you will need to find the values of $m$ that work, and this requires identifying points of intersection between the line and the curve.  Did you make any progress on that initial part of the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Solve $y=mx=\frac x{1+x^2}$ to get $x=0,\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-m}m}$. Thus, for $0<m<1$, the intercept value of $x$ is real and two curves enclose a region. Its area is integrated as
$$ \int_0^{ \sqrt{\frac{1-m}m}}\left(\frac x{1+x^2}-mx\right) dx=\frac12\ln\frac1m-\frac12(1-m)
$$